# UICollectionViewCell count always return 0

Tags: ios, swift2, uicollectionview

Using Singleton class in my app, just created a json array. In the UICollectionView i return that singleton class with shared instance as follows

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print("Count: ",InsuranceManager.sharedInstance.InsTypeListArray.count) // Output Count : 0

    return InsuranceManager.sharedInstance.InsTypeListArray.count
}
```

The count is always "0". So that the collection view cells are not displaying.The singleton class:

```
import UIKit

class InsuranceManager {

static let sharedInstance = InsuranceManager()

var InsTypeListArray = [InsuranceType]()
var TypeArray =  [InsuranceType]()

var CompListArray = [Companies]()

func getInsuranceDetails() {

    if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("type", ofType: "json") {
        do
        {
            let data = try NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe)
            let jsonObj = JSON(data: data)
            if jsonObj != JSON.null
            {
                print("jsonData:\(jsonObj)")
                if let items = jsonObj["type"].array
                {
                    // Removing the old data from Insurance type array
                    self.InsTypeListArray.removeAll()

                    for item in items
                    {
                        var type = InsuranceType()

                        type.id = item["id"].int
                        type.name = item["name"].string
                        type.selectedQuantity = 1
                        type.imageName = item["imageName"].string

                        // Adding new data into Insurance type array
                        self.InsTypeListArray.append(type)
                    }
                    print("Insurance List Array Count:\(self.InsTypeListArray.count)")
                }
            }
            else {
                print("could not get json from file, make sure that file contains valid json.")
            }
        }
        catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    else {
        print("Invalid filename/path.")
    }
}
}
```

The count value becomes 0 so the collection view cells were empty.

```
struct InsuranceType
{
    var id: Int?
    var name: String?
    var selectedQuantity: Int?
    var imageName: String?
}
```

My json file is:

```
{
"type": [
    {
              "id": 1001,
              "name": "Vehicle",
              "imageName": "vehicle"
    },
    {
              "id": 1002,
              "name": "Health",
              "imageName": "health"
    },
    {
              "id": 1003,
              "name": "Life",
              "imageName": "life"
    },
    {
              "id": 1004,
              "name": "House",
              "imageName": "home"
    },
    {
              "id": 1005,
              "name": "Legal Protection",
              "imageName": "legal"
    },
    {
              "id": 1006,
              "name": "Travel",
              "imageName": "travel"
    }
]
}
```

Based on my values in json "type" file, want to display in UICollectionView. Can any please help me what is the actual problem in my code. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you never call getInsuranceDetails function. You only get arrayValue. You can call the function or do it in the initialization